# Pythonic way to pass keyword arguments on conditional

Tags: python

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

```
if authenticate:
    connect(username="foo")
else:
    connect(username="foo", password="bar", otherarg="zed")
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? "Don't repeat yourself" is a good rule to follow, but not if it makes your code more complicated.

Comment: It won't be that much more complicated, so I value DRY over complexity in this case.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. You could add them to a list of kwargs like this:

   ```
   connect_kwargs = dict(username="foo")
   if authenticate:
      connect_kwargs['password'] = "bar"
      connect_kwargs['otherarg'] = "zed"
   connect(**connect_kwargs)
   ```

   This can sometimes be helpful when you have a complicated set of options that can be passed to a function. In this simple case, I think what you have is better, but this could be considered *more pythonic* because it doesn't repeat `username="foo"` twice like the OP.
2. This alternative approach can also be used, although it only works if you know what the default arguments are. I also wouldn't consider it to be very "pythonic" because of the duplicated `if` clauses.

   ```
   password = "bar" if authenticate else None
   otherarg = "zed" if authenticate else None
   connect(username="foo", password=password, otherarg=otherarg)
   ```

Comment: Option 1 is more lines and less straight forward than the original question =/

Comment: Option 2 is perfect if you only need to set one value depending on what value some other thing is.

Comment: Option 2 sometimes causes trouble and should be avoided in my opinion. In some libraries with optional key word arguments that take an object as argument, I saw stuff like `if x in kwargs:` followed by e.g. `print(x.info)`. This would raise an exception if `x == None`, as it doesn't have the property `.info`

Answer (score 7):

The OP's version is actually ok in this case where the number of unconditional arguments is low compared to the number of conditional ones. This is because only the unconditional arguments have to be repeated in both branches of the if-else construct.  However, I often run into the opposite case, i.e. the number of unconditional arguments is high compared to that of the conditional ones.

This is what I use:

```
connect( username="foo", 
         **( dict( password="bar", otherarg="zed") if authenticate else {} ) )
```

Comment: This is what I was expecting somehow but it looks kinda ugly

Comment: This is what I would use either.

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd throw my hat in the ring:

```
authenticate_kwargs = {'password': "bar", 'otherarg': "zed"} if authenticate else {}
connect(username="foo", **authenticate_kwargs)
```

Answer (score -2):

Or, more concisely:

```
connect(**(
    {'username': 'foo', 'password': 'bar', 'otherarg': 'zed'}
    if authenticate else {'username': 'foo'}
))
```

Comment: It is a single expression that avoids repeated references to a temporary for accumulating the arguments to pass.

Comment: I meant with respect to the original. It's the exact same thing as the OP, just rearranged.

Comment: Well, yes; but when I wrote "or, more concisely", I **didn't** mean with respect to the original (but to the other answer) ;)

Comment: Besides being not so concise, in my opinion it also adds ambiguity. Obviously, the code is not as clear as above.

Comment: How is it any less Pythonic? Conditional expressions are perfectly well understood. It reads like English, in the same word order, as follows: "Connect with keywords from the resulting dict: <this dict>, if asked to authenticate, otherwise <that dict>".

Comment: It's not Pythonic because it is cramming too much into a single logical line.  Python is not about clever one-liners.